# Allow only 4 Domain's to access certain content on another site

Tags: javascript, php, html, dns

I am using 4 promotional pages (all on different domains) for a service I sell on another domain.

All 5 pages/sites is using "plain" PHP and HTML, no wordpress or other CMS.

So on my sales site I have a login form (written in js) that I want only to be showed if the referer is from my other 4 promotional pages (domains).

**So what I need help with is a sctipt that do the following:**

People coming from PRdomain1.com, PRdomain2.com, PRdomain3.com and PRdomain4.com will see:

HEADER

CONTENT

LOGIN FORM

FOOTER

**and if** url to my salesite is typed in directly into addressfield **OR** come from other domain than my 4 PRdomains they will see:

HEADER

CONTENT

FOOTER

**1) Preferably, well crucial than ;-) , it should be compatible with most common browsers. It must be secure (the LOGIN FORM part) in the sense that it should not be retrievable in other way than from the PRdomains as referer.**

**2)  IT MUST WORK, SHOULD NOT MATTER if the PRdomains uses http/https or if the subpage is different, example, PRdomain1.com/landing_page2.php**

**3) It should not take lot of load? My PRdomain's, all of them, generates massive amounts of traffic to the sales page.**

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What's not working?

Comment: If you control the other domains, set a cookie. When the users go to the site where you want to show the login form, check for the cookie and show the content.

Comment: @Alex Howansky sorry, fixed now

Comment: Note that referrer can't be trusted (it can be overwritten by the client) so *any* solution that relies on it can't be secure. That said, it shouldn't be a big deal to display the login form based on referrer. It's just a form. You're not actually logging them in because of the regerrer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jQuery at your page, like this:

```
HEADER

CONTENT

<div id="#login" style="display: none">LOGIN FORM</div>

FOOTER

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (
{
  if ( document.location.hostname == 'prdomain1.com' || document.location.hostname == 'prdomain2.com' || document.location.hostname == 'prdomain3.com' || document.location.hostname == 'prdomain4.com')
  {
    $('#login').css ( 'display', 'block');
  }
});
</script>
```

With this code, your *LOGIN FORM* will be hidden by default because of *style="display: none"* CSS at <div> tag, and if the current page hostname (accessed by *document.location.hostname*) has what you're looking for, the script change the *display* CSS attribute to show the div content.

Comment: thanks! Is that solution secure? I mean in the sense that it does not matter if the PRdomains uses http/https or if the subpage is different, example, https://PRdomain1.com/landing_page2.php ? Also, wonder if it does not take lot of load? My PRdomain's, all of them, generates massive amounts of traffic to the sales page....

Comment: I am not sure but would it be "safer" putting the login part within PHP tags instead of using DIV ?

Comment: It's ok to use it at client side. If your page are generated using PHP, you can check at server side and print only if the referrer are on your white list, like: if ( strpos ( "prdomain1.com", $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]) !== false || strpos ( "prdomain2.com", $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]) !== false) { echo "FORM LOGIN"; }

Comment: This won't work -- document.location.hostname and $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] contain the hostname of the current page, OP wants a conditional on the referring hostname.

Comment: sorry for all confusion, the OP should be updated with all info now (i hope)

Comment: @Alex Howansky you have a workable solution for my requirements ? That allows "conditional" referring hostname as you mentioned?

Comment: Just use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but note the security caveats I mentioned.

Comment: @Alex Howansky so I'll use enani's solution above and replace all instances of "document.location.hostname" with "$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']" or ? If not it would have been highly appreciated if you could post your solution as an answer thanks?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution, but I'm not an expert in this so perhaps someone else herecan confirm??

```
<?php
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (preg_match("/prdomain1.com/",$referrer)) {
      echo 'ALL CONTENT INCL. LOGIN FORM HERE');
} elseif (preg_match("/prdomain2.com/",$referrer)) {
      echo 'ALL CONTENT INCL. LOGIN FORM HERE');
} elseif (preg_match("/prdomain3.com/",$referrer)) {
      echo 'ALL CONTENT INCL. LOGIN FORM HERE');
} elseif (preg_match("/prdomain4.com/",$referrer)) {
      echo 'ALL CONTENT INCL. LOGIN FORM HERE');
} else {
      echo 'ALL CONTENT WITHOUT LOGIN FORM HERE');
};
?>
```